# #import <FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h> is not fount

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree, braintree-sandbox

After installing the pod file project will shows the #import  file is not found error.I didn't have any idea to solve this problem.if any one knows, please pin me. latestly i installed the Braintree pod. after that i got this error 
[image: my pod file is here:]

[image: Geofire.m file is here.]

Comment: This is not swift, it's Objective-C. Have you tried building the App? By hitting `command` + `b` This usually compiles the dynamic frameworks so Xcode recognises them.

Comment: Geofire.m file is always in Objective c right

Comment: how to solve this problem – Erik Terwan

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an **Objective-C** example for you. Just follow my instructions.

1. The pod file you need to install is **pod 'FirebaseDatabase'**

[image]

2. In you UIViewController class or AppDelegate, import the firebaseDatabase like the following manner
   [image]
3. Build and run the project. Hope this should help you.